# Why is CloudFlare blocking file uploads?

Tags: 7, ajax, files, civicrm

I have a simple form where people raise IT helpdesk requests (oh, the irony...) and this creates a case in CiviCRM.  It's an unsophisticted but cheap helpdesk system for the few requests we get.

A user reported today of being blocked by CloudFlare.  On investigation it was because they tried to upload a screenshot of their issue.  We have a simple 'upload a file' field and have had no issues in the past. CKEditor and IMCE are not used - just native Drupal.

The rule triggered in CloudFlare is XSS/HTML injection  - b910aec795a44492b783da68301de41f from the Managed Ruleset.

I checked myself and on trying to upload a PNG file I get a window pop up with:

[image]

This is what I see CloudFlare side:

[image]

Checking our submissions, I can see that screenshots were uploaded early September this year, so either this is a Drupal change or a CloudFlare rule tightening.

Any ideas?  I could just disable the rule, but that is not a good practice without understanding the issue.  We are using Drupal 7.98 with CiviCRM 5.66.  We are upgrading to Drupal 10 and I have checked - it also gets triggered on our 9.5x and 10.1.x test systems.